# How to reduce number of screens on HTC Sense android phones?

Tags: htc-sense, performance, screen, htc-desire-hd

I was wondering, is there a way to reduce the number of screens available with HTC sense phones to say 5? Just I find that 7 screens is excessive for my needs, and I heard I can get a decent performance / battery boost from having less screens.

So is there a way to reduce the number of screens without using a custom launcher (which I think gets rid of HTC sense?)

Currently I just have my two side screens blank, but that looks off when you zoom out, however I have found that even that has produced a noticeable improvement on my Desire HD

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the number of screens and still use the HTC Sense UI. At least not in any of the versions I've seen.

You can uninstall it or turn it off, but then you won't have free access to all of the HTC widgets, if you like those.

If you really want the performance kick you'll get from less screens in total, and therefore using less RAM, you'll have to go back to Vanilla Android.  Simply using less widgets, as you've done, will certainly help somewhat.

I feel you pain too, I really only need 3 screens for my favorite widgets and folders, but I kind of like some of the HTC widgets.

Comment: ah ok. That's a pitty. Hope HTC will add it in future upgrades!

Answer (score 4):

In general, the less widgets you use on your home screens, the better performance your phone is going to have (less processing for widgets).

If you want to reduce the number of homescreens, then I suggest switching to another home launcher such as LauncherPro which will let you change how many homescreens you have. LauncherPro has some similar widgets to HTC's Sense too.

Answer (score -1):

use Go launcher ex.
i'm using it for nearly as long as i have the DHD.
very customizable, lots of themes and widgets even own locker screen (go locker)
and: it's free!

Comment: The OP asked "without using a custom launcher"!